# MS SQL and tideSDK

Tags: sql-server, tidesdk, tidekit

I want to query with tideSDK a MS-SQL database. How can I realize this in tideSDK?

My approach was to extend PHP with PDO SQLSRV. But I do not come on.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want however there was no native support for MSSQL in TideSDK. Our recent effort TideKit has native support for MSSQL along with other SQL and no SQL databases including Mongo and CouchDB. TideKit is releasing soon. You can find out more at http://tidekit.com or following on twitter at https://twitter.com/tidekit.